# Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'. and error Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden in https://jcenter

Tags: react-native, gradle

After updating Gradle to 6.8.3, running my `react-native` app shows this error:

```
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.61.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.61.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.61/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.61.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.61/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.61.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?